Call SOAP GET API using groovy script in CRM
I'm trying to call a SOAP(GET) using groovy in Oracle CRM.
In CRM there's option to register Web service where WSDL, Authorization is defined(Attaching a screenshot for reference).
Now I'm trying to call the service with the following code:
def GetRentalReservationRequest =
[
    startPosition :1,
    pageSize :1,
    filters:
    [
      filter:
      [[
        fieldName :'companyCode',
        fieldValue :'PG',
        operator :'EQ',
      ]]
    ]
]
      
adf.webServices.Get_Reservation_Soap.GetRentalReservation(GetRentalReservationRequest)


I am getting "Bad response: 405" error.
Help me out
The SoapUI payload looks like this(Working properly):
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:mes="http://wynnesystems.com/rm/schema/message" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:type="http://wynnesystems.com/rm/schema/type">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-B9C20D7AF11D042C0917173948874032">
            <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            <wsu:Created>2024-07-02T07:15:08.345Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:GetRentalReservationRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:startPosition>1</mes:startPosition>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:pageSize>10</mes:pageSize>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:filters>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <type:filter>
               <type:fieldName>companyCode</type:fieldName>
               <type:fieldValue>PG</type:fieldValue>
               <type:operator>eq</type:operator>
            </type:filter>
         </mes:filters>
      </mes:GetRentalReservationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


Here's link to the web service defined: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qSR1kXISrnfjYtODWHve6DTbX2SnT5a8/view?usp=sharing
